# Отличие mod_dos от mod_evasive

Tags: apache, apache-modules

В чем отличие `mod_dos` от `mod_evasive`? Порылся в инете, ничего полезного не нашел, кроме того, что в `mod_dos` нет защиты от брутфорса. Поделитесь советом, что и в каком случае лучше использовать.

Answer (score 1):

по-моему, основное различие - evasive не дружит с ITK, в то время как dosevasive вроде как нормально реагирует на него (:

да и отбиваться от ддоса апачем, имхо, далеко не лучший вариант, ни один мод не выдержит длительной атаки и всё равно упадёт...